# paypal payment api doesn't work with property "payee"

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

*I already took a look into the question that people keep saying this question is duplicated to, but I couldn't figure out how to deal with it with my code. I need an explanation. Thank you*

I'm new to paypal APIs so I'm kind of confused right now. creating transaction only works when I don't specify payee property, but how would paypal know who to send the money when there's no payee specified?

Here's the code

```
$(function() {
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'
        client: {
            sandbox:    'xxxxxx',
            production: 'xxxxxx'
        },

        commit: false, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '5.00', currency: 'USD' },
                            description: "TEST",
                            payee: { email: "seller-inventory@gmail.com" }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
                console.log("payment", payment)
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal');
})
```

Error code:

[image]

Comment: Possibly you need to include the merchant id, then? I'm just guessing now, I have zero experience with this but I'm intrigued. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-payee

Comment: @MeghanArmes I don't really get the difference between merchant_id and email that both are used for seller's info

Comment: Right, yeah -- it looks like they offer a sandbox to test API calls; not sure if that would help here, but I'm out of ideas, I'm sorry. :( https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/test-the-api/

Answer (score 0):

In the transaction object you need to have the items list with the items you are trying to sell. The mail also needs to exist.

If you don't specify the mail paypal send the money to whom has generated the client id key.

Also the items sum and currenct needs to match with the amount sum and currency

Try this (change sandbox id and the payee email need to exist in paypal):

```
$(function() {
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'
        client: {
            sandbox:    'yourclientid',
            production: 'xxxxxx'
        },

        commit: false, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '5.00', currency: 'USD' },                                
                            payee: { email: "seller-inventory@gmail.com" },
                            item_list: {
                               items: [
                                  {
                                    name: "hat",
                                    sku: "1",
                                    price: "5.00",
                                    currency: "USD",
                                    quantity: "1",
                                    description: "Brown hat."

                                  }]}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
                console.log("payment", payment)
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal');
})
```